# Suppressing node styles for certain nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, positioning, calc, intersections, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings, shapes, shapes.misc, shapes.symbols, shapes.geometric, patterns, backgrounds, trees, shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\small
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape, every node/.style={draw, very thick, black, rounded corners=5pt, inner sep=5pt, align=center, drop shadow}]
\node at (0,0) (invp){}
([shift={(0:3.5cm)}]invp.center) node (fin){}
([shift={(0:3.5*.5cm)}]invp.center) node (inu){}
([shift={(-90:1.8cm)}]inu.center) node (ind){}
([shift={(0:3.5cm)}]fin.center) node (shar){}
([shift={(0.:3.5cm)}]shar.center) node (invo){}
;
\node[rectangle, blue, outer color=blue!40, inner color=white, text width=1.68cm, minimum height=2cm] at (invp.center) {xxxxxx};
\node[rectangle, purple, outer color=purple!40, inner color=white, text width=1.4cm, minimum height=2cm] at (fin.center) {xxxxxx};
\node[rectangle,  green!40!black, outer color=green!70!black, inner color=white, text width=1.88cm, minimum height=2cm] at (shar.center) {xxxxxx};
\node[rectangle, brown!80!black, outer color=brown!60, inner color=white, text width=2.4cm, minimum height=2cm] at (invo.center) {xxxxxx};
\node[black, draw=none] at (ind.center) {Invest};
\draw[line width=1.4mm, black!60!white, latex'-, shorten >=26pt, shorten <=30pt] (invp.center) -- (fin.center);
\draw[line width=1.4mm, black!60!white, -latex', shorten >=30pt, shorten <=26pt] (fin.center) -- (shar.center);
\draw[line width=1.4mm, black!60!white, -latex', shorten >=38pt, shorten <=32pt] (shar.center) -- (invo.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I make certain nodes not use the node style definition?

For example defining the nodes `inu` and `ind` without drawing the border and drop shadow, and displaying the text "invest" without the drop shadow

Comment: Instead of using `every node`, you should use `\tikzset`, for example (1st solution). Or you can put the escaping nodes to a `scope` with `every node` redefined (2nd solution).

Comment: @JouleV Thank you. How to use tikzset and use it for certain nodes only; then defining the nodes position without applying tikzset. In your example, the text invest still has a dropshadow

Comment: That solution is not as good as the second solution, because the number of "normal" nodes is too large. Look at my answer for the second solution. (Edit: Thanks for pointinf that out. I'm currently working on an edit...)

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I put the `\node` commands of these two node to a `scope` and redefine `every node` inside that `scope`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, positioning, calc, intersections, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings, shapes, shapes.misc, shapes.symbols, shapes.geometric, patterns, backgrounds, trees, shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\small
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape, every node/.style={draw, very thick, black, rounded corners=5pt, inner sep=5pt, align=center, drop shadow}]
\node at (0,0) (invp){};
\node at ([shift={(0:3.5cm)}]invp.center) (fin){};
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={very thick, black, rounded corners=5pt, inner sep=5pt, align=center}]
\node at ([shift={(0:3.5*.5cm)}]invp.center)  (inu){};
\node at ([shift={(-90:1.8cm)}]inu.center)  (ind){};
\node[black, draw=none] at (ind.center) {Invest};
\end{scope}
\node at ([shift={(0:3.5cm)}]fin.center)  (shar){};
\node at ([shift={(0.:3.5cm)}]shar.center)  (invo){};
\node[rectangle, blue, outer color=blue!40, inner color=white, text width=1.68cm, minimum height=2cm] at (invp.center) {xxxxxx};
\node[rectangle, purple, outer color=purple!40, inner color=white, text width=1.4cm, minimum height=2cm] at (fin.center) {xxxxxx};
\node[rectangle,  green!40!black, outer color=green!70!black, inner color=white, text width=1.88cm, minimum height=2cm] at (shar.center) {xxxxxx};
\node[rectangle, brown!80!black, outer color=brown!60, inner color=white, text width=2.4cm, minimum height=2cm] at (invo.center) {xxxxxx};
\draw[line width=1.4mm, black!60!white, latex'-, shorten >=26pt, shorten <=30pt] (invp.center) -- (fin.center);
\draw[line width=1.4mm, black!60!white, -latex', shorten >=30pt, shorten <=26pt] (fin.center) -- (shar.center);
\draw[line width=1.4mm, black!60!white, -latex', shorten >=38pt, shorten <=32pt] (shar.center) -- (invo.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know if this is what you are looking for.

---

Edit: This is the `\tikzset` solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, positioning, calc, intersections, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings, shapes, shapes.misc, shapes.symbols, shapes.geometric, patterns, backgrounds, trees, shadows}
\tikzset{
    escape/.style={very thick, black, rounded corners=5pt, inner sep=5pt, align=center},
    notescape/.style={draw, very thick, black, rounded corners=5pt, inner sep=5pt, align=center, drop shadow}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\small
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\node[notescape] at (0,0) (invp){};
\node[notescape] at ([shift={(0:3.5cm)}]invp.center) (fin){};
\node[escape] at ([shift={(0:3.5*.5cm)}]invp.center)  (inu){};
\node[escape] at ([shift={(-90:1.8cm)}]inu.center)  (ind){};
\node[notescape] at ([shift={(0:3.5cm)}]fin.center)  (shar){};
\node[notescape] at ([shift={(0.:3.5cm)}]shar.center)  (invo){};
\node[notescape,rectangle, blue, outer color=blue!40, inner color=white, text width=1.68cm, minimum height=2cm] at (invp.center) {xxxxxx};
\node[notescape,rectangle, purple, outer color=purple!40, inner color=white, text width=1.4cm, minimum height=2cm] at (fin.center) {xxxxxx};
\node[notescape,rectangle,  green!40!black, outer color=green!70!black, inner color=white, text width=1.88cm, minimum height=2cm] at (shar.center) {xxxxxx};
\node[notescape,rectangle, brown!80!black, outer color=brown!60, inner color=white, text width=2.4cm, minimum height=2cm] at (invo.center) {xxxxxx};
\node[black, draw=none] at (ind.center) {Invest};
\draw[notescape,line width=1.4mm, black!60!white, latex'-, shorten >=26pt, shorten <=30pt] (invp.center) -- (fin.center);
\draw[notescape,line width=1.4mm, black!60!white, -latex', shorten >=30pt, shorten <=26pt] (fin.center) -- (shar.center);
\draw[notescape,line width=1.4mm, black!60!white, -latex', shorten >=38pt, shorten <=32pt] (shar.center) -- (invo.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]